# How to add a JAR library withou an IDE?

Tags: java, jar, windows-8, classpath

I'm facing difficulties on adding a JFreeChart library on my Java project (I use Windows 8). This is what I've already done:

1 - Unzipped JFreeChart

2 - renamed the archive `jfreechart - 1.0.19` to `jfreechart`

3 - Added it's path to classpath: `.;C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\projects\EP2 - IA\jfreechart - 1.0.19\lib\jfreechart.jar;`

4 - Added in the beggining of my Java file: `import jfreechart.*;`

5 - Copied the `jfreechart` archive to the same directory of my project

But when I try:

```
java -classpath jfreechart.jar MyClass.java
```

it returns that the "jfreechart package does not exists"

As I'm an old school programmer that still uses Notepad, I've found nothing useful on Google about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong import statement.  Try this instead:

```
import org.jfree.*;
```

You also may need the following library:

```
jcommon-1.x.y.jar
```

For future reference, you can view the contents of a JAR file using the command line `jar` command:

```
jar -tvf jfreechart-1.0.19.jar
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question: this CMD command returned a lot of things; is there a easier way to discover the import statement for a JAR?

Comment: The _easiest_ way to discover the import path is to use an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse.  If that be not possible then you can Google for help.  A cursory search uncovered [this great tutorial site](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JFreeChart/article.html) which showed how to import the JFreeChart library.